# Lambda expression join one to many relations resulting multiple objects

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, lambda

This is a simple question really, i have 2 table Products and Images in Products andd Images are shown below

```
Products(Urun)
--------
ProductID(UrunID)
ProductName(UrunAdi)

IMages(Resimler)
-------
ImageID(ResimID)
ImageName(ResimAdi)
ProductID(UrunID)
Path(Path)
```

in asp.net i m using repeater to list PRODUCTS in div but my lambda expression results ;lists div with images not with products (actually products but since a product has more ımage than one it shows every ımage )

ihow can i change code to show only for 1 image , first image if posible?

```
()
right1.datasource = Contextim.MyContext.Urunlers.Join(Contextim.MyContext.Resimlers, u => u.UrunID, r => r.UrunID, (u, r) => new { UrunID = u.UrunID, UrunAdi = u.UrunAdi,OzellikID=u.OzellikID, Path = r.Path ,KategoriID=u.KategoriID }).ToList().Where(d=> d.KategoriID==catid).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

that Solution Is Group By Used

```
  right1.datasource =(From u in Contextim.MyContext.Urunlers
                      Join r in  Contextim.MyContext.Resimlers  on  u.UrunID  equals r.UrunID
                     Where u. KategoriID== catid
                     Group new {u,r}  by p. UrunID into jj
                     Select new {
                                  UrunID = jj.FirstOrDefault(). u.UrunID, 
                                  UrunAdi = jj.FirstOrDefault(). u.UrunAdi,
                                   OzellikID= jj.FirstOrDefault(). u.OzellikID,
                                   Path = jj.FirstOrDefault(). r.Path ,    
                                   KategoriID= jj.FirstOrDefault(). u.KategoriID
                                 }).ToList();
```